# "right" vs "correct"

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

Except for the fact that we use **right** to denote direction, what is the difference between the two terms *right* and *correct*?

Also, which one is the preferred construction between these two?

> Am I **right**?

or

> Am I **correct**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'd say that there is a subtle distinction between the two, in that "correct" implies that the given answer (or answers) is definitive and absolute, as might be the case, for example, with a simple maths problem.

In contrast, "right" would be better for an answer which, although considered appropriate, is still matter of opinion (even if most people agree). This might apply, for example, to a question of ethics ("is this the right thing to do?"); again, using "correct" here would imply that there is an absolute answer that no-one could possibly disagree with.

"Right" can still be used in places where "correct" would be appropriate (such as a maths problem), but not the necessarily the other way around.

Comment: If "right" implied the meaning you suggest, then one would say "Is this a right thing to do?" rather than "the right".

Comment: @Shinto: hmmm; I see what you're saying. If the speaker suspects that there are multiple possible right answers, then this ought to be OK...yet it sounds wrong. Perhaps there's an implicit assumption that there is an optimally right answer (i.e. one that is somehow more right than the others), which is specific enough to justify using "the" rather than "a".

Comment: In my view there is no difference. I would say the opinion that Steve Melnikoff gives is an interpretation that is not in the two words. *correct* is the Latin form and *right* is basically the same connected with Latin rect-us. We say *That's absolutely right*. But *right* has also the meaning *to the right side*, so correct is sometimes clearer as it is unambigous.

Comment: I agree with rogermue. They are 100% synonymous with each other and this answer is purely point of view (in other words: it is neither right nor correct). "Is this the right thing to do?" and, "Is this the correct thing to do?" are identical to each other (other than that it is a different word). Both words have different sets of definitions - that is quite possibly what is causing the confusion. Under the correct (or right) circumstances the meaning of each word is 100% interchangeable. Personal preferences do not denote fact.

Answer (score 13):

I always make sure to use 'correct' when someone is asking about directions.  Otherwise it's like Laurel and Hardy:

Them: So I go left on Elm Street?

Me: Right.

Them: Oh, I'm sorry. So I turn RIGHT on Elm. Then-

Me: No, no, you go LEFT on Elm.

Them: Huh?!

Answer (score 6):

By definition they have the exact same meaning.

Modern English, however, is a mash-up of Anglo-Saxon (Old English) and Norman (French), linguists often refer to it as Anglo-Norman English. This gives us many cases of synonymous words such as "trash"(OE) and "garbage"(F) or "weep"(OE) and "cry"(F).

Because the Normans were usually the only ones educated, English words of French origin are often considered to be more technical, thus "correct"(F) carries a more definitive implication. Whereas words from the Old English are considered to be more emotional (and therefore found more often in poetry) thus "right"(OE) is more often used to imply opinion.

Comment: What a beautiful answer!

Answer (score 5):

They are synonyms, but I'd reserve the use of correct for either formal usage ("The mathematical proof was shown to be correct") or as a verb ("correct one's behavior")

The writer will otherwise risk sounding pedantic or pretentious.

Comment: When something is true, legitimate or right, you can say it's correct.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I'd say *right* refers to the moral, culturally acceptable and generally practiced, while *correct* refers to the legal, law-backed and generally adopted.