# "Is this the right way?" vs "Is this the correct way?"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“right” vs “correct”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/right-vs-correct)

I've had this question for a long time. Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> Is this the **right** way?
>
> Is this the **correct** way?

Comment: Either is right. Both are correct.

Comment: Both are right. Can't say which is correct, though. @Robusto is half right, maybe not correct.

Comment: Very similar: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/right-vs-correct

Comment: @SteveMelnikof: Similar, but not identical, I'd say: these words have different connotations in different contexts, and these are different phrases/expressions. For example, your answer as quoted below is less applicable here than to the other question. Voted to reopen.

Comment: @Cerberus I was going to agree with every single word of what you said, but then I scrolled down to see that the OP has actually *accepted* an answer that is *nothing but* a verbatim quote of Steve's answer from that other question. Apart from that being just wrong (that reputation should really go to Steve), the OP has straight out admitted that had he seen that other question earlier, this question here simply wouldn't exist.

Comment: @RegDwigh: Yes, that is odd. Even some OPs don't know when one case is different from another...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Steve Melnikoff](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/303/steve-melnikoff) in [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1723/right-vs-correct) said:

> I'd say that there is a subtle distinction between the two, in that
>   "correct" implies that the given answer (or answers) is definitive and
>   absolute, as might be the case, for example, with a simple maths
>   problem.
>
> In contrast, "right" would be better for an answer which, although
>   considered appropriate, is still a matter of opinion. This might
>   apply, for example, to a question of ethics ("is this the right thing
>   to do?" or "is he the right guy for this job?"); again, using
>   "correct" here would imply that there is an absolute answer that
>   no-one could possibly disagree with.
>
> "Right" can still be used in places where "correct" would be
>   appropriate (such as a maths problem), but not the necessarily the
>   other way around.

I think this pretty much answers your question.

Comment: Some context is lacking. Steve's answer applies to the phrase "am I right? / am I correct?", but it is less appropriate in this case. For example, in the contrastive phrases given, it seems less likely that "is this the right way?" is about ethics.

Answer (score 6):

They would be used in different circumstances. For example, if you were lost, you'd be more likely to ask 'Is this the right way?' rather than 'Is this the correct way?' But the answer to your question is that both are grammatical.

Comment: Though if you are lost, there's an advantage in favouring "correct" and making it less likely that your advisor would mirror your language and stick in a *right* meaning *correct* that you could mistake as a *right* meaning the opposite of *left*.

Answer (score 3):

They're both grammatically correct. Indeed, they're both grammatically identical: "Is this the [adjective] way?"

They're also both commonly used.

They are close in meaning, and there are circumstances where you could use either.

"Correct" has a nuance of precision that would make it more appropriate when you are looking for an exact answer, (rather than if there are several right ways, and you just want to know you have one of them). Even here though, you could still use either.

Comment: What is meant by "both identical"?

Comment: @Kris a colloquial pleonasm. Strictly it should be "Indeed, they're grammatically identical:".

Comment: +1 This is the best answer (despite the pleonasm, which will not doubt be set right or corrected later...).

Comment: @Cerberus ah, what's a colloquialism between friends? I'm inclined to leave it, Kris' questioning of it, and my explanation, as a bonus point on another question of usage :)

Comment: @JonHanna: Very well...I just had to use "right" and "correct", as a bonus point to...I don't know.